# Game Programming Gems series still of value?

Tags: c++

Former Nintendo dev Mark DeLoura wrote a series of books called "Game Programming Gems".

(http://www.satori.org/game-programming-gems/)

Do these books still contain valuable concepts, considering where games are today, the engines that are available, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the concepts are valid, especially when it comes to creating an Entity Component System (which is often vaguely discussed). The last couple books are the most valuable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Have you read them?

Comment: Yes, I've read them. And I would also recommend Game Coding Complete 4th edition.